# Using bass strings on guitar

Tags: guitar, maintenance, strings

Would it be safe to use a 0.065 bass string as a B string(tuned to Bb) on a 7 string guitar with a scale length of 26.5?

Comment: It would be useful to know how the rest of the guitar is strung - you need a matched tension over all strings to be kind to the neck. Also it'll give us an opportunity to match to the existing strings. I know that is not your question, but there are ramifications.

Comment: @tim the guitar is strung with 10-46 tuned to standard half step down

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can look up string tensions in the [D'Addario String Tension Supplement](http://daddario.com/upload/tension_chart_13934.pdf), however your scale length is not covered in their tables.

They do, however, provide a general formula

T (Tension) = (UW x (2 x L x F)<sup>2</sup>) / 386.4

.. where UW is the unit weight in lb/in, L is the scale length in inches, and F is the frequency of the note in Hz. Presumably if they used metric measures, there wouldn't need to be a fudge constant.

[B♭ is 58.27 Hz.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_key_frequencies)

The unit weight of their 0.065 string is 0.0007956

So the tension of your proposed string is:

0.0007956 * (2 * 26.5 * 58.27)<sup>2</sup>) / 385.5 = 19.68lbs

That's comfortably in the range you'd expect of an electric guitar string, so should work fine.

To work out the ideal string to go with your other strings, work out the tension for your other strings, and use the formula in the opposite direction to find the unit weight that gives you B♭ at that tension:

UW (unit weight) = (T x 386.4) / (2 x L x F)<sup>2</sup>

Comment: I'd wonder if the bass string would even fit in the bridge of a guitar....

Comment: @VarLogRant It actually fit, my guitar has Floyd Rose bridge and the tuning peg is weirdly large. I didn't wind it though after reading slim's answer.

Comment: It's easy to forget... we always notate guitar an octave higher than it sounds, (but we never actually explicitly write that anywhere on the sheet music). I remember when I sat down one day trying to figure out what the heck was going on... I couldn't figure out why A440 matched 5th fret on the high E (two octaves above middle C, according to "music"), it sure confused me.

Answer (score 1):

The *low* Bb (the 7<sup>th</sup> string I'm assuming you'll tune *lower* than your open Eb right? The **Open A is 110Hz**); so… Bb is .5 X 116.5Hz (58.25Hz actually, recheck the chart on the D'Addario string site).

This changes the math of course… 0.0007956 * (2 * 26.5 * 58.25)<sup>2</sup>) / 386.4 = 19.62lbs… It's just about right, if you want to go totally "Gonzo" tune it to an Ab (1 finger barre power chords in the two low strings, bwhahaha!!! *fast*), seriously… you can also do *low* I-V bossa/samba bass lines with a single finger if you tune your 7<sup>th</sup> down a 5<sup>th</sup> instead of a 4<sup>th</sup>.

Ab would be 0.0007956 * (2 * 26.5 * 51.9)<sup>2</sup>) / 386.4 = 15.57lbs

As a comment on detuned 7-string playing… you might want to consider a little heavier on the bottom end than a standard set of "10's", sometimes the 6 & 7 strings can get a little "floppy" and if you press too hard (especially with jumbo frets), you can get intonation problems (sometimes things just get a little too loose, but the 26.5" scale should help, just mentioning it so you're aware of it). I used to use a set of "11's" with a plain third, and it was over a decade ago, I've forgotten what I used for a low A string (55Hz, I didn't normally detune).

Answer (score 1):

Given that your bottom E is .046", a .060" or .062" will do the job. A .065" will maybe give a little more grunt to your sound, but would feel a little tight. That string rarely gets bent, so it doesn't need to be too loose.  Any thicker than .065" won't do the neck any favours in the long term.You mention 'bass string'. An ordinary guitar string will be better, as a string for a bass guitar (if that's what you mean) is way too long. I'm not sure if the make-up of a .065" guitar string is any different from a .065" bass guitar string - probably not. Just shorter.When you have a successful set-up, please let us know: theory is all very well - practice is better.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the fact that anytime someone asks "[is] it safe,"  I start thinking about escaped Nazi officers posing as dentists :-),  I would recommend as a general rule *against* using any string that you're going to tune to a higher open pitch than its design pitch.  After adjusting for the open-string length, of course (a bass E-string would have the same applied tension if used as an A-string on a 3/4 length neck, roughly speaking).
If you do try to tune a string high, it'll have a rather short lifetime.  Anecdotally, the lifetime of a cello C-string that I mistakenly mounted as a G-string had a life of less than 30 seconds :-( .

Comment: With bass guitar strings, I'd worry more about the lifetime of the instrument's neck, than the lifetime of the string.

Comment: @slim  so you're saying guitar necks are wimpier than cello necks, or guitar strings are tougher than cello strings? just joking :-)

Comment: I'm assuming electric guitar strings, which work at much higher tensions than nylon cello strings.

Comment: @slim who uses nylon?  All cello strings I know are wound metal.  there may be a few gut string specialists out there, but not in measurable numbers.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft, that's just the outer winding, the inside is gut or nylon (preferably gut, of course); I always used gut, it's been 20 years though... but here's some "Pirastro Gold's" for sale http://www.bing.com/shopping/search?q=pirastro+gold+gut+strings&qpvt=pirastro+gold+gut+strings&FORM=HURE

Great strings, I highly recommend them, I always found their tone much richer than nylon (quite a bit more expensive of course).
But yes... electric steel core strings (electric guitar/bass/steel string acoustic) are a lot more tension than violin/viola/cello/double bass or... classical guitar

Comment: @DavidAxtellMooreII  you are right about the various compositions available.  All the same, my cello  strings are under a lot more tension than the E and G (low) strings on my electric bass. Granted that's not true of elec. guitars

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - I just know that overall there is more tension, it's why electric guitar/bass & steel string acoustics employ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truss_rod in their design (adjustable metal rods) inside of their necks to counterbalance that high tension and keep their necks straight; whereas I've never seen such a design on a nylon/gut stringed instrument design. I've wondered about it though, my 35-40 year old Paulino Bernabe (classical guitar) has developed just a touch too much neck bow and the action is too high now (great tone though), I've never had any trouble with my Violins.

Comment: @DavidAxtellMooreII seems we're wrong or out of date about this - http://www.thomastik-infeld.com/upload/TI_cello%20folder%2003_07print.pdf modern cello strings with ~30LBS tension and apparently all-metal construction.

Comment: @ slim - Wow... all-metal Cello... I wonder if this means they will start putting truss-rods in Cellos now? Notice that the "synthetic core" sets do range lower (19-21lbs) than the steel-core. Personally I'm not sure I would use the steel-cores for this reason alone, I may take a look around the web and see if anyone has had neck problems with their vintage instruments, (I would never take the chance myself, maybe on a cheap student/practice instrument, but my good violin is worth too much). They mention a "modern" sound, I guess I'm more of a traditionalist, I always preferred gut over synth.

Comment: @ slim -  it does make me wonder about "electric" violin/cello/upright (yes they make them all), we kind of left them out of the conversation I guess; even though I play electric guitar too (mostly now, I started on violin when 9, but pretty much quit after the first couple years of college); anyways, I never came closer to playing electric violin than putting a pair of headphones on mine and plugging them in backwards as a weird kind of micro-phonic pick-up (distortion sounds cool, so does delay) and plugging into my guitar rig. Perhaps they're built to take the increased stress better now.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violin_construction_and_mechanics/#Strings
This seems like a pretty relevant section on Wiki (of course that's as subjective as anything, but then... there would be no science without us arguing about it right? notice all the "[citation needed]" notes); from my older experience, it seems pretty correct to me. Of course, that any comparison of tone is subjective should go without saying on this site (but usually doesn't), as I mentioned above, my own personal preference was always wound gut strings (I used Pirastro golds), IMO, the tone was more "alive", try em'.

Comment: a couple more relevant links I ran across (a lot of references to newer metal composition strings for Cello, not sure how this compares to Violin strings, I've been out of that game too long). http://www.paulperleycellos.com/chatterfurthertonalimprovements.html and also the "Maestro..." forums (they've got some obviously knowledgeable luthiers on there), http://www.maestronet.com/forum/index.php?/topic/318437-improving-instrument-response/
I'm sure any Cellist will enjoy the read.

Comment: "It is generally agreed that gut and perlon-type strings sound best on violins and violas. They are certainly the most popular with players regardless of musical styles. Many players like Pirastro Eudoxa, Oliv and Gold Label gut strings. Perlon strings are essentially synthetic gut strings. Recommended brands include the perennial favorites Thomastik Dominants, though a dizzying number of variants on this type of string are now on the market: Zyex, D'Addario Pro Arté, and Pirastro Tonica or Aricore, and Savarez Crystal..." "Strings" section, last line ;-)
http://www.lutherie.net/care.html

Comment: "super-sensitives" ha-ha, (I imagine most people would agree with him there... "you get what you pay for").

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is so picky about strings and tension and life of their necks.  I say just go ahead and give it a try.  Guitar necks can take more tension than they are normally subjected to.  Everyone told me don't put steel strings on a baritone uke, so I didn't, until one day when I was mad about something, I threw my ukulele across the room.  It left a 12 inch dent in the drywall and was completely unharmed.  Not even a scratch!  I immediately strung it with steel strings and use it like a tenor guitar.  That was five years ago and still no neck issues, no fret issues, no tuner issues...it just keeps playing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that it will be very floppy at that gauge.